# What does the metacharacter, '?' match?

Tags: regex, perl

I researched and i know that the '?' is used to match if the result occurs 0 or 1 times in a matching function. Unfortunately, i cannot find a clear example on what exactly does '?' matches.

Cheers.

Comment: The general term is "quantifier", and there are a lot of examples in Learning Perl. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Regular expression

```
co?at
```

Would match `coat` and `cat`

Comment: Thank You! That is a great example.

Answer (score 8):

`?` itself doesn't match anything. It's just a modifier that modifies the preceding atom (e.g. character or group). It does what you say: The preceding atom must appear 0 or 1 times in order for the regex to match.

Comment: I know that '?' itself doesnt do anything. Say, '"Mr. John" =~ m/Mr?/'. What does this match for?

Comment: This was not your question. You asked what `?` matches and it doesn't match anything. `/Mr?/` matches both `M` and `Mr`.

Comment: Re "anything else", `\t`, `[abc]`, captures, any of the `(?...)`, etc. It causes the previous *atom* to match 0 or 1 times.

Comment: @ikegami: Thanks, that's the word.